# To access current login user friends data using facebook api V2.1 in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is possible in V2.1 current login user friends data in array.?

I am confusion so much when i have RID about that.use bellow permission

If any review or testing need by facebook for the permission.?

& My app. already permission about **read_friendlists** & **user_friends**.

**Result** array Give only which current user Friends are member of application that given only

```
            <?php
            require 'facebook.php';


            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '523738927757085',
            'secret' => '3c672c913e6c1b5d9400d94efc1cd566',
            ));

            if($facebook->getUser() == 0){
            //$login = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            $login = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            echo "<a href= '$login'>Login with Facebook</a>";
            }
            else{
                $facebook->getLoginUrl();
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
                $friends = $facebook->api('/me/');
                $friendlist = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
                $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();


            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($user_profile);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<br/>";

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($friends);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<br/>";

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($friendlist);
            echo "</pre>";
            }
```

Suggest me some solution.
Thank You

Comment: you really don´t need "read_friendlists". friendlists are not friends.

Comment: and those variables are weird. "user_profile" is /me, "friends" are /me/friends.

Comment: _“Give only which current user Friends are member of application that given only”_ – that is by design. And you should not try and circumvent that, otherwise your app might get blocked by FB.

Comment: @CBroe : Thank's for given information.